# alsa snd_device_name_get_hint with card index

Tags: c++, linux, audio, alsa, pcm

I created a custom sound device in ~/.asoundrc or /etc/asound.conf.
Now i call my sound client with the parameter for the sound device and want to check if this device exists.
I found it easier to use the actual card and device index instead of names, which can be different (long or short version).

Unfortunately the "Name" hint of `snd_device_name_get_hint` has the syntax "devicename:CARD=name,DEV=index" like "iec958:CARD=Adapter,DEV=0", but i need "devicename:index,index".
Is there alternative function to get exisiting snd_devices?

Comment: That is a valid device name. You can look up the card ID in `/proc/asound/cards`, but why bother?

Comment: Actually the syntax "devicename:CARD=index,DEV=index" is also valid, when you try to call it from the console. Its shorter and definite, when you have two devices connected with the same name.